# Convert a custom object type to array using custom algorithm

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a custom class called **HTMLElement**.

```
class HTMLElement
{
private $name;
private $value;

function __construct($name,$value) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->value = $value;
}

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name){
    $this->value = $name;
}

public function getValue(){
    return $this->value;
}

public function setValue($value){
    $this->value = $value;
}

public static function ConvertToHTMLElement(HTMLElement $obj){
    return new HTMLElement($obj->name,$obj->value);
}

}
```

Now I want to create an associative array using the property **$name** as the key and the **$value** as the value.

The **$value** may contain either a string or an array or HTMLElement object type

This is where I'm passing my value to my algorithm.

```
$tree = new HTMLTree();
$newArr = $tree->ConvertToArray(new HTMLElement(
"table", (array(
     new HTMLElement("tr", array(
        new HTMLElement("td", "Name"),
        new HTMLElement("td", "Age"),
        new HTMLElement("td", "City")
    )
)
))));
```

**This is my algorithm**

```
class HTMLTree
{

public function ConvertToArray($htmlElement){
    if(is_array($htmlElement)){
        $arr =array();

        foreach ($htmlElement as $singleElement){
            $arr = $this->Convert($arr,$singleElement);
        }
        return $arr;
    }else{
        return $this->Convert(array(),$htmlElement);
    }

}

private function Convert($arr,HTMLElement $element){;
    $name = $element->getName();
    $value = $element->getValue();

    if(is_string($value)){
        $arr =array(array_merge(array($name=>$value)));
        return $arr;
    }else if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $elem){
           $arr = array_merge($arr,$this->Convert($arr,$elem));
        }
        return array($name=>($arr));
    }
    else if(is_object($value)){
        $arr = array_merge(array($name => $this-
>Convert($arr,$value)));

    }
    return $arr;
}
}
```

The problem is I'm getting an output as the following
[image]

Whereas the output I want is this
[image]

Where have I gone wrong in the algorithm?

**UPDATE**

The new HTML Tree

```
$tree = new HTMLTree();
        $newArr = $tree->ConvertToArray(new HTMLElement(
            "table", array_merge(
                array(
                    new HTMLElement("tr", array(
                        new HTMLElement("th", "Name"),
                        new HTMLElement("th", "Age"),
                        new HTMLElement("th", "City")
                        )
                    ),
                    new HTMLElement("tk", array(
                        new HTMLElement("th", "Name"),
                        new HTMLElement("th", "Age"),
                        new HTMLElement("th", "City")
                        )
                    )
            )
        )));
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
$tree = new HTMLTree();
$newArr = $tree->ConvertToArray(new HTMLElement(
    "table",
    array(
        new HTMLElement("tr", array(
                new HTMLElement("th", "Name"),
                new HTMLElement("th", "Age"),
                new HTMLElement("th", "City")
            )
        )
    ,
        new HTMLElement("tr", array(
                new HTMLElement("td", "sjs"),
                new HTMLElement("td", "sss"),
                new HTMLElement("td", "ddd")
            )
        )

)));
```

Expected Array structure

```
Array (
    [table] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [tr] => Array (
                            [0] => Array (
                                    [td] => Name
                                )
                            [1] => Array (
                                    [td] => Age
                                )
                            [2] => Array (
                                    [td] => City
                                )
                        )
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [tk] => Array (
                            [0] => Array (
                                    [td] => Name
                                )
                            [1] => Array (
                                    [td] => Age
                                )
                            [2] => Array (
                                    [td] => City
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me more simple, you could created a new method `toArray()` in your HTMLElement class, called recursively, if the `$value` is an HTMLElement.

There is no more need of `array_merge()`.

Here is the full program :

```
class HTMLElement
{
    private $name;
    private $value;

    function __construct($name,$value) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name){
        $this->value = $name;
    }

    public function getValue(){
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value){
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function toArray() {

        // Handle scalar values
        $val = $this->value ; 

        // Handle HTMLElement values
        if (is_object($this->value)) {
             $val = $this->value->toArray();
        } 

        // Handle array values :
        elseif (is_array($val)) {
            foreach ($val as &$item) {
                if (is_object($item)) {
                    $item = $item->toArray();
                }
            }
        }

        // Return Key/Value pair
        return [$this->name => $val] ;
    }

    public static function ConvertToHTMLElement(HTMLElement $obj){
        return new HTMLElement($obj->name,$obj->value);
    }

}

$elm = new HTMLElement(
    "table", array(
        new HTMLElement("tr", array(
                new HTMLElement("th", "Name"),
                new HTMLElement("th", "Age"),
                new HTMLElement("th", "City")
            )
        ),
        new HTMLElement("tr", array(
                new HTMLElement("td", "sjs"),
                new HTMLElement("td", "sss"),
                new HTMLElement("td", "ddd")
            )
        )
    )
);

$newArr = $elm->toArray() ;
print_r($newArr);
```

Outputs :

```
Array (
    [table] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [tr] => Array (
                            [0] => Array (
                                    [th] => Name
                                )

                            [1] => Array (
                                    [th] => Age
                                )

                            [2] => Array (
                                    [th] => City
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [tr] => Array (
                            [0] => Array (
                                    [td] => sjs
                                )

                            [1] => Array (
                                    [td] => sss
                                )

                            [2] => Array (
                                    [td] => ddd
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. Thank you very much @Syscall. Not all heroes wear red capes xD

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap array to be consistent with others, after array_merge.

```
private function Convert($arr, HTMLElement $element){
    $name = $element->getName();
    $value = $element->getValue();

    if(is_string($value)){
        $arr = array(array_merge(array($name=>$value)));
        return $arr;
    }else if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $elem){
            $arr = array_merge($arr,$this->Convert($arr,$elem));
        }
        if (!isset($arr[0])) $arr = array($arr); // <<< Code modified here
        return array($name=>($arr));
    }
    else if(is_object($value)){
        $arr = array_merge(array($name => $this->Convert($arr,$value)));

    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Outputs :

```
Array (
    [table] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [tr] => Array (
                            [0] => Array (
                                    [td] => Name
                                )
                            [1] => Array (
                                    [td] => Age
                                )
                            [2] => Array (
                                    [td] => City
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Although, I added another object to array. Basically the to the 1st index. Again the same problem comes. How to handle this programmatically?

Comment: @AkilaRandil Could you post your new `HTMLTree` please?

Comment: @AkilaRandil To be fair, I don't understand what you want to get. I've updated the anwser (see section update). Could you please tell me the structure you expect?